# Parse content from CK Editor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

My application is an asp.net C#:
I use CK Editor to edit an article, and then insert to SQL Database. Now I want to export this article to docx file. All functions work well, but the content of article after export in docx file like below :

```
<ul>
    <li style="text-align: justify;">
        Đối với t&ocirc;i, kh&oacute;a huấn luyện vừa qua rất bỗ &iacute;ch t&ocirc;i đ&atilde; học được rất nhiều kiến thực v&agrave; gi&aacute; trị thiết thực, bổ &iacute;ch cho c&ocirc;ng việc của t&ocirc;i .</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li style="text-align: justify;">
        Hỗ trợ ứng dụng tiếp theo &quot;9 nguy&ecirc;n tắc .</li>
</ul>
```

How to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with HtmlAgilityPack and HtmlDecode

```
string content;
var htmldocs = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
            {
                OptionFixNestedTags = true,
                OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
            };
            htmldocs.LoadHtml(content);
string convert = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmldocs.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

Comment: So this stores the content without the HTML tags?